# Can I solder the Pi-zero hardware on its back side? If Yes then How and what are the effects on it?

Tags: rpi.gpio, bluetooth, pi-zero

I am working on raspberry pi zero 1.3 , I wanted to add a bluetooth 4.0 on its back side , So Is that possible with zero1.3 to solder on back side to add a hardware(BLE4.0)?

[image]

Comment: I mean, it surely is possible because both sides of the hole (on the 40-pin connector) are plated. Just be careful with the pins positions and you are set to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are add-on boards (HATs) for that purpose, e.g. [IoT HAT for Raspberry Pi: A must-have for Pi Zero](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/redbearinc/iot-hat-for-raspberry-pi-a-must-have-for-pi-zero) or [HubPiWi Blue - Pi Zero Add On Wifi + Bluetooth + 3 USB Ports](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/pico-learber-board/hubpiwi-blue-pi-zero-add-on-wifi-bluetooth-3-usb-p).

Such boards connect to the Pi via the GPIO connector. So pin ordering notwithstanding (e.g. HAT might be on top, so back-to-back might reverse the pin-order) it seems feasible to actually solder some hardware to the Pi to get Bluetooth functionality.

While [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#schematics-and-mechanical-drawings) does not provide an official schematics for the Pi Zero there are some results from *reverse engineering* known. This [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20210225030803/http://hackers.gallery/841/misc/raspberry-pi-zero-pad-probing) lists the following test pin functions:

> PP    Description
> PP1   USB +5V Input
> PP6   GND
> PP8   3.3V
> PP14  SD CLK
> PP15  SD CMD
> PP16  SD DAT0
> PP17  SD DAT1
> PP18  SD DAT2
> PP19  SD CD
> PP22  USB D+
> PP23  USB D-

So most of them won't get you far. However it is possible to solder an USB Bluetooth dongle directly to the USB data lines there. Note that you cannot do this *and* use the on-board USB connector simultaneously.

Comment: and what about the pins at back pp1 and pp6 except from the gpio's? how they can be utilized if wanted to use one of them?